# Outer measure definition how to understand intuitively

Tags: measure-theory, intuition

> definition: Let $A \subset R^n$. The Lebesgue outer meausre of A is $$m^*(A)=\inf \{ \sigma(S) \colon \text{S is a covering of A by closed intervals} \}$$

I know $\sigma(S)=\sum v(I_k)$, where $I_k$ is a closed interval

How am I supposed to understand this intuitively? And what does it mean by covering of A?

Comment: Covering means that every point of the set is in one of those intervals. Intuitively, it is the minimal total length of a collection of intervals needed to contain all points of the set.

Comment: When you don't get the def. in one book, you could check for an alternative def. $\displaystyle m^*(A)=\inf \{ \sum_{n\in M}\mathscr l(I_n): A\subset\bigcup_{n\in M}I_n \}$, where $M\subset\mathbb N$ and $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$

Comment: A cover (covering) of $A$ is a family $C$ of sets such that $A\subseteq \cup C=^{def}\cup_{f\in C}\,f.$ That is, any $a\in A$ belongs to at least one member of $C$. A sub-cover of $C$ (when speaking only of coverings of $A$) is any $D\subseteq C$ such that $D$ is also a covering of $A$.... If every $f\in C$ is open (is closed) then $C $ is called an open (a closed) cover, as an abbreviation for "cover of $A$ by open (by closed) sets."

Comment: The whole point is that it a possibly countable cover.